# jquery mobile datebox iterating through the shown dates

Tags: jquery-mobile, datebox

I am using the jquery mobile datebox at http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/demos/fullopt.html In particular I am using the calbox option at http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/1.1.0/jqm-datebox-1.1.0.mode.calbox.js

How can I iterate through all days shown on the calendar and get the date in the format "YYYY-MM-DD"? It is easy to get the day only since that is being shown so you can extract it from the dom - but is their a way to get the year and the month portion as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could look at

```
$('element').datebox('getTheDate')
```

but that would give you an incorrect month/year for the "other" months dates.  What's your intended purpose, maybe there is a better way to go about it? (Or, if you have a compelling use case, maybe it's something that needs to be added...)

Comment: Thanks - I thought I had solved the problem by doing what you suggested. For the year and month, I look at the input field's value and store it as soon a click happens. For the day I can easily get it from the displayed elements. Did not understand the other month dates part of your comment. Btw, thanks a bunch for this awesome utility!!!

Comment: Some more background - my goal is to mark the selected day . I was trying to do this by changing the css of the selected element (e.g. by toggling a class). However, this works if I select one day. The moment I select another day, the class change I made for the prior day I selected vanishes. Hence I thought of iterating through all the days and setting them (since I can remember which days were selected in the past separately.

Comment: For now I only show one month - so there is no other month at display (just to avoid the other months problem you mention).

Comment: you *could* probably add the dates to the highDates or highDatesAlt array (option).  It uses a different (user-definable) jQM theme swatch - and that would "persist" with multiple clicks.

Comment: Hi J.T. After adding the highDatesAlt array - how do I programmatically refresh the calendar to reflect the change? I tried "$('#datetime').trigger('datebox', {'method':'refresh'});" but it does not work. Also, how do I figure out when the user has clicked the button that changes month in the calendar (so I can do the UI changes and/or "refresh" the calendar as needed? Thank you!

Comment: you can catch the datebox event (method == 'set') to see when a date is clicked.  (there should be another variable in there that lets you know which date was selected.  To refresh, $("#datetime").datebox('refresh'); should do it.

Comment: Thaks JT That is what I did after I learned it from the answer to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895573/jquery-mobile-datebox-intercepting-the-date-select-click.